# Why does material-ui v4 declare useTheme but doesn't implement?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm quite confused by the new Hooks API in Material-uiV4.

@material-ui/core declares `export default function useTheme<T = Theme>(): T;` but doesn't implement this, as it errors out.
The documentation says you should import from @material-ui/styles which works, but the type is set to unknown.

`export default function useTheme<T>(): T;`

Why doesn't the @material-ui/styles version have T = Theme by default?
Why does @material-ui/core have a declaration to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are links to the relevant code and TypeScript declaration files:

- TypeScript declaration file for `useTheme` in @material-ui/core:

  - https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/styles/useTheme.d.ts
- TypeScript declaration file for `useTheme` in @material-ui/styles:

  - https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui-styles/src/useTheme/useTheme.d.ts
- Code for `useTheme` in @material-ui/core:

  - https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/styles/useTheme.js
- Code for `useTheme` in @material-ui/styles:

  - https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui-styles/src/useTheme/useTheme.js

`@material-ui/styles` provides styling functionality in a manner that is completely independent of `@material-ui/core` (`@material-ui/core` is dependent on `@material-ui/styles`, but `@material-ui/styles` is **not** dependent on `@material-ui/core`).

The `ThemeProvider` and `useTheme` functionality in `@material-ui/styles` could be used with **any** theme structure, so it is accurate for it to have a type of unknown. The `useTheme` in `@material-ui/core` is mostly a wrapper around the `@material-ui/styles` version, but it assumes that the structure of the theme matches Material-UI's default theme and if no theme has been provided (via `ThemeProvider`) then it will return the default theme (whereas the `@material-ui/styles` version has no concept of a "default" theme).

> The documentation says you should import from @material-ui/styles

I'm curious to know what part of the documentation says this. So long as you are using Material-UI's theme structure, I would recommend importing `useTheme` from `@material-ui/core/styles`.

Comment: I have these two declaration files for useTheme.
Using VSCode, these two are available, with their aforementioned types in them.
One is either clearly from the core package, or I am missing something.
    
`node_modules/@material-ui/core/styles/useTheme.d.ts`    
`node_modules/@material-ui/styles/useTheme/useTheme.d.ts`

Comment: I have updated my answer now that I better understand your question.

Comment: That clears some things up. The documents don't 'state' that you 'should' import from @material-ui/styles but rather use that import in examples. After reading your updated answer you'd think that is because of the abstraction. I have since changed all imports through core, rather than styles package directly. Works like a charm. The error that had the imports fail in the first place, triggering this question, was having multiple versions of material-ui as dependencies.